# Extract ClassSymbols for method's parameter bounds

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros

I'm trying to extract `ClassSymbol`s for all type parameters' bounds of a method.

The "solution" I came up with:

**Macro annotation implementation:**

```
@compileTimeOnly("Compile-time only annotation")
class classSyms extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro impl
}

object classSyms {
  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*) = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees.toList foreach {
      case q"$mods def $templatename[..$typeparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $body" =>
        typeparams foreach {
          case q"$mods type $name[..$tparams] >: $low <: $high" =>
            if (!high.isEmpty) {
              //requires FQCN, does not work with imported names
              val classSymbol = c.mirror.staticClass(high.toString)
              println(classSymbol)
            }
        }
    }
    q"..$annottees"
  }
}
```

**Example**:

```
package pack.age

trait Test

package another.pack.age

import pack.age._

trait Bar{
  @classSyms
  def foo[M <: pack.age.Test, T](): Unit //works ok


  @classSyms
  def baz[M <: Test, T](): Unit //throws scala.ScalaReflectionException: class Test not found.
}
```

**The problem** is such requirements of specifying fully-qualified class name as a parameter bound does not make this macro implementation very useful (no one wants to write this long fqcn stuff, especially if the name is imported).

Is it possible to extract `ClassSymbol` by an *imported* name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `c.typecheck`.

Replace

```
val classSymbol = c.mirror.staticClass(high.toString)
```

with

```
val classSymbol = c.typecheck(tq"$high", mode = c.TYPEmode).symbol.asClass
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I missed the point of typechecking. Reading the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes) I found that _In addition to outlining the structure of the program, trees also hold important information about the semantics of the program encoded in symbol (a symbol assigned to trees that introduce or reference definitions), and tpe (the type of the tree). By default these fields are empty, but typechecking fills them in._

Comment: @SomeName `Test` in different places can have different meaning. `Test` referring specifically to `pack.age.Test` becomes known after typechecking the tree in current context `c`.

Comment: @SomeName See phases of compilation: `parser` (here source-code strings become untyped trees), `namer` (here `Test` becomes `pack.age.Test`), `typer` (here untyped tree `q"..."` becomes typed i.e. with types attached to all its nodes) ... https://typelevel.org/scala/docs/phases.html

Comment: @SomeName Maybe in your specific use case running namer without typer would be enough but there is no API for that. But more important is that in Scala generally names can't be resolved without typechecking. For example implicits can make impact on name resolution and implicits are resolved during typechecking.

Comment: @SomeName On contrary to def macros manipulating typed trees (without `c.untypecheck`) macro annotations manipulate untyped ones (without `c.typecheck`). Macro annotations are expanded before typechecking , def macros are expanded during typechecking.